# embed bulk data for post-deployment script in sql server data tools (SSDT)

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

In class libraries it is possible to use embedded resources and access them in code.

Can I use embedded resources (e.g. tab separated text files) in ssdt as well to use them as 'seeding data' in a post deployment script? I would prefer to not use hard-coded paths.

Comment: Is the data for dev/test environments or production? Can the data always be bulk inserted or does it need to be diffed against the target db resulting in a mix of insert/update/delete statements?

Comment: @Keith good point. Are post deployment scripts not just run when I tear down etc.? I guess you would only apply dacpacks in a production. So maybe this issue does not exits?

Comment: Post deployment scripts are only run during the tear down phase, or more specifically, after the deployment script or dacpac is deployed. I've never used dacpacs so I'm not sure how they handle the deployment of data (I've always assumed they did not). Schema Compare and publishing are 2 other good methods for deploying to production, but they do not intrinsically handle bulk data. So whichever method you go with for deployments, you still have to address the bulk data issue.

Comment: In my scenario the bulk data is just used to seed the system after tear down.

Comment: didn't get you. could you please explain the case with examples?

Answer (score 0):

As is you can not do that, since the scrip will be execute at SQL server which has no access to the local drive were the file is. What I have done before is to copy the file inside the script as a variable XML Type.

example: Declare @X XML = N '..........' and then manipulate the variable to insert in the desired table.